# Qt Macdeploy tool alternative for windows

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, static-libraries

Hi I am trying to make my qt app run just copying the exe. With hours of static build I succeded it however; I discovered that there is a tool for mac named 'macdeployqt' doing all the process for you.
So I wondered if any equivalent tool or script exists for windows. It will get the exe extract dependencies, creates qt.conf file and put the dll's and exe into right paths. 
What I mean here is not about creating setup package, just a folder containing all necesseray libraries etc.

Comment: what about windeployqt.exe ?

Comment: oh, I didn't noticed that this exe is here. Bu not sure if it has the sam functionality with macdeploy. Whatever will give it a try thanks.